# Why can I extend an arrow function if I can't access its output?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Given the following example:

```js
class X extends (() => {
  return "spam"
}) {
  constructor() {
    super() // Can't access
    this.msg = X() // Can't access
  }
}

let x = new X()
console.log(x.msg)
```

Why can I extend an arrow function if I can't access its output? What is logged is:

```
error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function
```

The definition of what is a class and what is a function is somewhat blurred in Javascript, considering [the "new" ES6 definitions](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-subclassing/).

Comment: Jesus, my eyes hurt! :D

Comment: It is blurred because they are the same thing. A class is just a different syntax on top of the already existing function mechanism that has a few rules on how it can be used (for instance classes cannot be invoked without `new`). Go outside of those rules and a class is still just a function.

Comment: in firefox 70.0b4 (64 bits) (on linux) you can't `TypeError: () => {
  return "spam"
} is not a constructor`

Comment: when transpiled using babel, the only error in your code is `this.msg = X();` for obvious reasons

Comment: @JaromandaX, it was on purpose, since I can't access that return. The problem is: Why is it acceptable to extend an arrow function in the first place?

Comment: @JaromandaX while I agree it's obvious to me, it may not be obvious to everyone present :)

Comment: `Why is it acceptable to extend an arrow function in the first place` it actually isn't - only gets past that hot mess when transpiling with `es2015-loose`

Comment: I don't get why that is supposedly allowed. As in, where that claim comes from, since arrow functions *cannot* be used with `new`, so they cannot be used to create instances, which in turn means they cannot be used as constructors. The very error here shows that you cannot do it any yet, OP claims you can. Why?

Comment: I ran that code on https://playcode.io/, if I skip the `this.msg = X() // Can't access` line, it's acceptable.

Comment: @EricsonWillians as has been explained, transpiling with babel in `es2015-loose` will silence the syntax error you'd get in native ES2015 syntax, because in ECMAScript 5, there was no such thing as a function that wasn't constructable unless it explicitly threw an error in the body. That site is transpiling the code in the editor to ES5 before execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That something compiles or executes does not mean that is valid or according to the specs. So you always need to check the specification about what is valid and what isn't. The relevant part to your question can be found in [14.6.13 Runtime Semantics: ClassDefinitionEvaluation](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-runtime-semantics-classdefinitionevaluation):

> ```
> [...]
> 5. If ClassHeritageopt is not present, then
>    a. Let protoParent be the intrinsic object %ObjectPrototype%.
>    b. Let constructorParent be the intrinsic object %FunctionPrototype%.
> 6. Else,
>    a. Set the running execution context's LexicalEnvironment to classScope.
>    b. Let superclassRef be the result of evaluating ClassHeritage.
>    c. Set the running execution context's LexicalEnvironment to lex.
>    d. Let superclass be ? GetValue(superclassRef).
>    e. If superclass is null, then
>       i. Let protoParent be null.
>       ii. Let constructorParent be the intrinsic object %FunctionPrototype%.
>    f. Else if IsConstructor(superclass) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
> [...]
> ```

And 6.f  states `Else if IsConstructor(superclass) is false, throw a TypeError exception.` and an arrow function is not a constructor.

So at the time when the class definition is evaluated, the engine would need to throw a `TypeError` error according to the specs.

And Chrome (76) in fact throws the error before `let x = new X()` es evaluated:

> Uncaught TypeError: Class extends value () => {
>     return "spam"
>   } is not a constructor or null

---

[7.2.4 IsConstructor ( argument )](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-isconstructor)

> is a function object with a [[Construct]] internal method.

`ClassHeritage` is defined as follows:

> ```
> ClassHeritage [Yield, Await]:
>    extends  LeftHandSideExpression[?Yield, ?Await]
> ```